# Where to find a proof of Alexsandrov 's theorem for convex function in dimension $1$?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

I need a proof of Alexsandrov theorem in dimension $1$:

Let be $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex function. Then $f$ has second derivate almost everywhere. More precisely we can write the second order Taylor expansion of $f$.

I have found a proof in dimension $n\geq 1$ in the book of Evans and Gariepy, 'Measure theory and finite properties of functions'.

Since I need this result only in dimension $1$, I would like to find a more simple proof.

Can somebody give me some references? Thank you very much!

Comment: See the references I posted [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=445211), especially **A Second Course on Real Functions** by van Rooij and W.H. Schikhof.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you!!!